# Show that $F_h(x)=\frac{1}{ C h^d} \int_{B(x, h)} f(y) d y$ is continuous

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

In $\mathbb{R}^d$ provided with a norm, we note $C=\lambda(B(0,1))$ the Lebesgue measure of the unit ball.
For $f \in L_{\text {loc }}^1\left(\mathbb{R}^d\right)$ and $h>0$, we consider $$F_h(x)=\frac{1}{ C h^d} \int_{B(x, h)} f(y) d y.$$ I need to show that $F_h$ is continuous ! By a variable change I have showed that $F_h(x)=\frac{1}{C}\int_{B(0,1)}f(x+hz)dz$ but I get stuck here ! I think I should use continuity theorem but $f$ is not continuous ! Any help is highly appreciated !

Comment: You don’t want to change variables. You want to argue directly that the indicator function of a slightly perturbed ball converges pointwise a.e to the indicator of the original ball. Geometrically this should be reasonable (if you move a ball/modify its radius by a little bit, then it is essentially the same ball).

Comment: If $f$ is integrable then $\int |f(x+h)-f(x)|dx \to 0$ as $ h \to 0$. This is proved in Rudin's RCA.